# How to put bullets only between items in a wrapping, in-line list

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to achieve the effect in the picture below where I have a wrapping, in-line list with bullets, but only placing the bullets in-between list items that occur on the same line. I am working in react. Any help is greatly appreciated! [image: wrapping list picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codepen.io/bartek-krakowski/pen/jOBNGOP

I split up the list into two sublists and added an exception using `:not(:first-child)`

```
<ul class="main">
  <li>
    <ul class="child">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2 </li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="child">
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
    .main {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .child {
      display: flex;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      
      li:not(:first-child) {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 5px;
        
        &::before {
          content: '';
          width: 5px;
          height: 5px;
          background-color: red;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 0;
          transform: translateY(-50%);
        } 
      }
    }
```